# Angular ng-repeat does not iterate over array of string items containing html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a div where I want to put checkboxes with text beside them.

I am getting this text from a database and adding to an array in javascript the html formatting and text that I want:

```
var textHtmlElement = '<label class="smallPadding"><input type="checkbox">' + text + '</label>';
textList.splice(textList.length , 0, textHtmlElement);
```

The titles array is returned from a function is then assigned a $scope variable:

```
$scope.list = service.getTextList();
```

However, when I try to ng-repeat over that array, the checkboxes and text does not show up.

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in list">
    {{ item }}
</div>
```

There is a scope variable called `list` when logging scope it to the console: `console.log($scope)`. What I found odd is that when I log `console.log($scope.list)`, it shows an empty array... If I explicitly do `$scope.list = ['1', '2', '3']`, the ng-repeat works, so I guess the problem is in this line `$scope.list = service.getTextList();`

How should I fix this?

**EDIT**
The getTextList() function in my service:

```
getTextList: function(){
    return textList;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
My service where I get my data and return the list of text:

```
app.service('service', function() {
    var textList = [];

    return {
        getTextList: function(){
            return textList;
        },
        dataQuery: function() {
            var text = "";
            . 
            . 
            .
            query.find({
                success: function (results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var object = results[i];
                        text = " " + object.get('text');
                        textList.splice(textList.length , 0, text);
                    }
            . 
            . 
            .
```

My html:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <label class="smallPadding"><input type="checkbox">{{ item }}</label>
</div>
```

My controller remains the same - though the array assigned to the $scope.list variable does not contain html. It is just data, as suggested. 
First, I call the dataQuery function in my service, then the getTextList function.

**Edit 3**
Working code.
I added the following around my `$scope.list = service.getTextList();`:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.list = service.getTextList();
}, 150);
```

The 150 ms timeout gives time for the query to finish getting the data which will be assigned to the $scope.list variable.

Comment: where is the 1st snippet of code?

Comment: It's inside a service where I do my database query.

Comment: So, you diagnosed that the problem is in `service.getTextList();` Why don't you post the code of `getTextList()` then? Also, you're doing it plain wrong. HTML should be generated by the view, not by services. Services should return data, not HTML.

Comment: why dont you just return your text and have the html in your html? what is the purpose of having it in a service?

Comment: @FelixGluschenkov come on. You need to post the relevant code if you want us to help you. How can we guess how textList has been initialized, where it comes from, etc. if you don't post the code?

Comment: The service returns `textList`. This variable is initialized this way: `var textList = [];`. Why are you surprised the service returns an empty array?

Comment: Because I add elements to the textList in dataQuery (see edit 2: `textList.splice(textList.length , 0, text);`). Then I return the textList after calling dataQuery. Shouldn't the array contain the elements I added?

Comment: Not if you never call dataQuery(). Or if the query fails. Nothing in your question indicates that you call dataQuery().

Comment: Indeed, I added that clarification at the end of edit 2

Comment: @JBNizet 'Or if the query fails': it didn't fail because then it would have given an error, but your comment made me think whether the query finishes before the call to getTextList as the resulting array would be empty if it didn't finish. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best Practice**

Do not use a service to manipulate the DOM in the way you have, its bad practice. instead use your service to get your array of text and then instantiate it in a controller.

From the controller you can bind your array returned to your `$scope` and in your html you should have something like this

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in list">
  <label class="smallPadding"><input type="checkbox">{{ item }}</label>
</div>
```

That is if I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the best practice tip. I've tried your suggestions, but it still doesn't work. See edit 2.

Comment: where do you get your array values from? http?

Comment: Oh, I got it to work :D It turns out that even though I call the Parse query before getting the array, the code continues to run on after the query. I.e. query gets called, get array is called (but query is still getting data).

Comment: I added a $timeout: see edit 3. It works, but could you tell me if its good practice to do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are populating a list from backend and you see a backend call taking some time. using ng-if is one of the best options I suppose because the element will not be loaded until the array has values. With the current method, there is no guarantee that even in 150 milliseconds you will have the data. Hope it helps someone.